# Storing values as an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following select values:

```
<select name="vibe_quiz_tags[]" id="vibe_quiz_tags" multiple="" class="chzn-select chosen select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
   <option value="">Select Taxonomy</option>
   <option value="4">Test1</option>
   <option value="5">Test2</option>
</select>
```

If both of these are selected then the values are stored in my database like the following:

`a:2:{i:0;s:1:"4";i:1;s:1:"5";}`

How would I assign those to get this same input in my database when I post this form?

Comment: That string is the result of `serialize()` called on the `vibe_quiz_tags` array.

Comment: try: serialize($_POST["vibe_quiz_tags"])  or change index in post

Comment: if you use mysql, use http://de2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php to create sql query.

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string is no long the best practice for preventing SQL injection, the best practice is to use prepared statements. Some argue to go even farther and use prepared statements to call stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

To safely save it to the database, you'd first sanitize the input, then used prepared statements to insert it into the database.  Something like:

```
 //Always sanitize first:
 foreach($_POST['vibe_quiz_tags'] as $val)
 {
   if(!($val == 4 || $val == 5 || $val === ''))
   {
     die('User attempted to game the system, or submitted invalid input.');
   } 
 }

 // Serialize the data. This will get the format you have in the question.
 $todb = serialize($_POST['vibe_quiz_tags']);

 $db = new mysqli(/* Your database parameters here*/);

 // Replace table and field with the correct table and field
 // Prepare the statement
 $stmnt = $db->prepare('insert into table (field) values (?)')
          or die('Database error: ' . $db->error);
 // Bind the parameter to be a string. Passing the serialized value.
 $stmnt->bind_param('s',$todb) or die('Database error: ' . $db->error);
 //Execute the statement.
 $stmnt->execute() or die('Database error: ' . $stmnt->error);
 // Close the statement.
 $stmnt->close();
 // Close the database connection.
 $db->close();
```